# Laptop and Pi directly connected via LAN cable, how to make the Pi give the Laptop a static IP without setting it on the Laptop?

Tags: networking

Is it possible to force the Pi to always give the same IP to the Windows laptop without setting the IP in the Windows Network settings?

[image]

Above settings should be **blank and set by the Pi**.

Answer (score 1):

in LAN enviroments with switches and so you have an DHCP server which distribute the IP adresses to the computers. You can configure the DHCP server in that way that it gives always the same IP address to the same Computer.
So in your case I suppose if you install an DHCP server on the PI and configure it in that way it might work.

Hope I could help you.

Best regards.
Kalle